# How to Change Drawer Position by using react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react navigation 3.9.1 .I want to open drawer from right or from left based on condition.

if i have tried following condition but it doesn't work
drawerPosition : isArabic ? 'right' : 'left' 
as routes is get loaded it does not get changed value of isArabic so the drawer position is not changing as i want to change the position of drawer.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46303188/dynamically-change-drawerposition-config-of-drawernavigator-in-react-navigation

Comment: I have used DrawerNavigator of React-navigation

Answer (score 0):

Seems there's no 'official' way of changing the drawer position dynamically. Still, the feature was left open for PR 
https://react-navigation.canny.io/feature-requests/p/dynamic-drawerposition

Meanwhile, the workaround will be creating two drawer navigators in the app and you can open the right drawer if the language is Arabic and vice-versa.

Referencing: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/780#issuecomment-370635948

The basic code structure would go like this.

```
import RightSideMenu from '~/RightSideMenu';
import LeftSideMenu from '~/LeftSideMenu';
import { .. } '~/screens'

const MainStack = StackNavigator(
  {

    Main: {
      screen: Main,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    Screen1: {
      screen:  Screen1,
      navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Main',
    navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        elevation: 0,
        shadowOpacity: 0,
      },
    },
  },
);

const MainDrawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    MainStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'MainStack',
    drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    drawerPosition: 'left',
    contentComponent: props => <LeftSideMenu {...props} />,
    drawerOpenRoute: 'LeftSideMenu',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'LeftSideMenuClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'LeftSideMenuToggle',
  },
);

const RootRoute = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    MainDrawer: {
      screen: MainDrawer,
    },
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
    },
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    contentComponent: props => <RightSideMenu {...props} />,
    drawerOpenRoute: 'RightSideMenu',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'RightSideMenuClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'RightSideMenuToggle',
  },
);

export default AppRoute;
```

With these options, you can control which drawer to open.

```
drawerOpenRoute: 'LeftSideMenu',
drawerCloseRoute: 'LeftSideMenuClose',
drawerToggleRoute: 'LeftSideMenuToggle',
```

Say...

`'isArabic' ? this.props.navigation.navigate('RightSideMenuToggle') : this.props.navigation.navigate('LeftSideMenuToggle')`

Hope this helps you.